# How to show div in if block in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have index.php, in index.php there is a login form with session. If username and password are correct, it would go to home.php. But if username or password is incorrect I want to show div above login form that contains an error message like this [image: Error Message].

I want this warning div is hidden and it will be shown only if username or password is incorrect. I've tried some other solution but none of them work, first If I put div in else condition, it will appear above login form no matter what the condition are. Second, if I put javascript to change style display = block, it won't appear in index page. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

**Index.php**

```html
       <?php
          session_start();
          if(isset($_POST['login']))   
          {
            $user = $_POST['user'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            if($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin") 
            {                                      
              $_SESSION['user']=$user;
            ?>
              <script language="javascript">window.location.href='home.php' </script>
            <?php
            } else {
            //What should I do here?                
            ?>
              <script language="javascript">document.getElementById("warning").style.display = "block" </script>
            <?php
            }
          }
        ?>

        <!-- Warning that I want to show if username or password is incorrect -->
        <div id="warning" class="w3-container w3-red w3-text-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-opacity" style="position: relative;margin-top: 20px;display:none">
            <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Incorrect Username or Password!
        </div>
        <!-- Login form -->
        <form class="w3-container" action="" method="post">
        </form>
```

**[EDIT]**

I finally solved the problem by following Sharky's suggesstion to put php code below warning div. In else case I'm still using javascript that will change style display of warning div to block. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, use stack snippets if you have complete code that can run a browser or 4 space indent (`{}` button) for other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your div is not showing, is because your javascript which sets the `display:block;` is being executed BEFORE that div is generated in your markup.

Simple scenario (which fails):

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <script language="javascript">
                document.getElementById("warning").style.display = "block";
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="warning" style="display:none;">hello</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

this will result to 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` because **the moment** javascript tries to get the element with id `warning` there is **only this markup "existing" in the browser**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            document.getElementById("warning").style.display = "block";
        </script>
```

do you see any div with id `warning` on the above markup? no, there isn't any div at all. in fact there is no `<body>` yet!

So in order for this to work, your javascript must go after that div. put it at the bottom just before the `</body>`. See the following, which works:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="warning" style="display:none;">hello</div>
            <script language="javascript">
                document.getElementById("warning").style.display = "block" 
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Now, about your code: if you do not want to move that big block of `if` you can just set a flag variable like

```
$need_to_show_warning = false;
if($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin") 
{                                      
    $_SESSION['user']=$user;
?>
<script language="javascript">window.location.href='home.php' </script>
<?php
} else {
//What should I do here?                
$need_to_show_warning = true;
}
```

then, AFTER your div:

```
    <!-- Warning that I want to show if username or password is incorrect -->
    <div id="warning" class="w3-container w3-red w3-text-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-opacity" style="position: relative;margin-top: 20px;display:none">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Incorrect Username or Password!
    </div>
<?php 
    if($need_to_show_warning)
    {
?>
<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("warning").style.display = "block"; </script>
<?php
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, both of them will be the same as my first case. The warning will appear even if I haven't filled username and passsword fields yet.

Answer (score 1):

The best way should be what you already tried: use the #warning div in the `else` case. Maybe it didn't work because you chose the wrong `else`?

```
<?php
      session_start();
      if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        if($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin") {                                      
          $_SESSION['user']=$user;
          ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href='home.php';</script>
          <?php
        } else {
          ?>
          <div id="warning" class="w3-container w3-red w3-text-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-opacity" style="position: relative;margin-top: 20px;">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
          <strong>Warning!</strong> Incorrect Username or Password!
          </div>
          <?php
        }
      }
    ?>

    //Login form
    <form class="w3-container" action="" method="post">
    </form>
```

Another tipp (which has nothing to do with your question, but may help anyway): instead of using a redirection with JavaScript, you could simply use php, so that the additional roundtrip to the browser is not needed any more:

```
header('Location: home.php');
```

This requires, that no 'normal' output is created before the `header()` call and would work in this example, but may fail if there is some html code before it.

Comment: this will not work. you just output a div with `display:none`.

Comment: You're right, I've forgotten to remove this style. I corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've tried your solution too .. but the warning will appear before I haven't filled username and password fields yet. I want the warning to be shown if user has filled the fields and only if username or password is incorrect :(

Comment: The warning can only appear if `$_POST['login']` is set *and* wrong credentials are applied to `$_POST['user']` and `$_POST['pass']`. If you just load the page, a `GET` request is used, so `$_POST` should not even be filled. I think, there must be some other problem. Can you give me the URL that you use, then I will have a look at least at the generated html.

Comment: I rebuilt my index page and suddenly it works! I don't know what happened but I follow @Sharky 's solution to put php code below warning div. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
   <?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_POST['login']))   
      {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        if($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin") 
        {                                      
          $_SESSION['user']=$user;
        ?>
          <script language="javascript">window.location.href='home.php' </script>
        <?php
        } else {
        //What should I do here?                
        ?>
            <!-- Warning that I want to show if username or password is incorrect -->
            <div id="warning" class="w3-container w3-red w3-text-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-opacity" style="position: relative;margin-top: 20px;">
                <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
                <strong>Warning!</strong> Incorrect Username or Password!
            </div>
            <!-- Login form -->
            <form class="w3-container" action="" method="post">
            </form>              
        <?php
        }
      }
    ?>
?>
```

Comment: this will fail due to reasons explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37674658/953684)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the OP had a display:none and was using Javascript to set it to show. There is no need to, since the div will be present only when the login fails. So I have removed the `display:none` and the `<script>` blocks from my answer.